# output psql results and errors to a file

Tags: postgresql, scripting

I want to display the results of psql queries on a file.In the log just the name DO for the anonymous Bloc is being displayed.

The following is being executed from a shell script file :

```sql
psql --host=${HOST} --port=${PORT_IP} --dbname=${DATABASE_NAME} --username=${USERNAME} -f $scriptSQL -v v1=$fichierLog -v v2=$annee
```

and here is the content of scriptSQL :

```sql
\o :v1
\timing on
DO $$
declare
    -- programme de lancement de la purge des redevances

    -- date creation : 20/02/09

    annee       varchar(4); --  annee a purger

begin

    annee := ':v2';



  -- lancement de la fonction de purge
    SELECT pckg_activ.purgeRedevance(annee);

end $$;

\timing off
\o
\q
```

nothing is being displayed apart from DO.

Is the DO Anonymous Bloc the reason why nothing is displayed on v1 (the output file) ?

Any solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RAISE NOTICE` must be used to display values in a DO block,
as in

```
DO $$ begin raise notice 'hello'; end $$;
```

Result:

```
NOTICE:  hello
```

If you do just a SELECT, here's what happens:

```
DO $$ begin select 'hello'; end $$;
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT : If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT : PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at SQL statement
```

Since it's an error, it doesn't go into the file designated by `\o :v1`

The output of `\timing` also won't go into that file.

The documentation says about `\o`:

> \o or \out [ filename ] \o or \out [ |command ]
>      Arranges to save future query results to the file filename or pipe
>      future results to the shell command command. If no argument is
>      specified, the query output is reset to the standard output.
>
> ...
>
> “Query results” includes all tables, command responses, and notices
>      obtained from the database server, as well as output of various
>      backslash commands that query the database (such as \d); but not
>      error messages.

To capture all the output, use redirection at the shell:

```
$ psql [options] >file 2>&1
```

---

Another problem is that the `:v2` variable cannot be expanded in the dollar-dollar-quoted string that constitutes the DO block (and it should be written as `:'v2'`, not `':v2'`, but anyway it doesn't matter here because there's no variable expansion in `$$`-quoted strings )

Both input parameters and output results are sadly difficult to manage with DO blocks.

For the input side, custom session parameters can be used, as shown below:

```
test=> \set var 'foo'
test=> set params.v1 to :'var';
SET
test=> show params.v1;
 params.v1 
-----------
 foo
(1 row)

test=> do $$ begin raise notice '%', current_setting('params.v1'); end $$;
NOTICE:  foo
DO
```

Comment: the problem is that even when i use PERFORM statement the output file is still empty , i think that at least the time which has been set when using \timing on needs to be displayed ?

Comment: Please the edit with the doc quote.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do shell redirection nor use \o in the SQL script.
`psql` has a flag for this:

> -o filename --output=filename
>
> Put all query output into file filename. This is equivalent to the
> command \o.